# Turning <span>s into paragraph

Tags: javascript, regex, gsap

I'm turning all characters and whitespaces into spans from paragraph and I'm animating those spans with `gsap`. The problem is, that the different letters lost connection with words and im getting a bad looking paragraph.

```
const quote = document.querySelector('.paragraph');
const quoteText = quote.textContent;
quote.innerHTML = quote.textContent.replace(
  /\S/g,
  "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"
);

const tl = new TimelineMax();
tl.staggerFrom(
  quote.childNodes,
  1,
  { opacity: 0, y: 200, ease: Power4.easeOut },
  0.02,
  () => {
    quote.textContent = quoteText;
  }
);
```

Then, when animation completes I'm assigning a previous paragraph text content, but the letters move
and its not looking good. What is a proper way of doing my animation?

Comment: I would ask you what is the requirement? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: You should make use of GSAP's [SplitText](http://greensock.com/splittext) :) It makes this sort of thing easy.